# How to pass custom data/parameters to Chromecast receiver via URL?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

Is it possible to have a Chromecast sender application to pass custom data to the receiver in the URL? The goal is to pass user-specific data to the receiver so it can generate the appropriate contents each time it's called.

An example of this would be a simple to-do list. When the user casts to their device, that user's data should be passed via URL to the receiver so that their task list can be loaded in the custom receiver.

I haven't seen any tutorials or much information on this in the Cast documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cast receiver URL is specified as a static URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO6hV.png) when you're registering/publishing the app on the Google Cast SDK Developer Console so it is not possible to add custom parameters.

However you can use the [Cast Messages system](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver#messages) to send data between a Cast sender and Cast receiver. It's similar to the messaging system in modern browsers.

Comment: The cast message system doesn't seem to work from mobile chrome.  Do you know of any workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean passing parameters as part of the receiver url that loads the receiver, the answer is no; there is no such thing. You can either use the customData that can be passed to the receiver in a number of APIs, or you can create a custom data channel if the former is not adequate for your needs.